# SDL_image Out of Scope

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-image

I'm trying to get off the ground  with SDL. SDL by itself works fine, I got the basic Hello World setup to work. However, trying to use SDL_image has caused me a ton of headaches. My current code (below) gives me the error 'Img_Load' was not declared in this scope' at line 17.

- My linker settings in Code::Blocks look like this: "-lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_image"
- Search directories are properly set up
- The required DLLs are in the folder with the EXE.

  ```
  include iostream
  include fstream
  include "SDL/SDL.h"
  include "SDL_image.h"

  using namespace std;
  const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 600;
  const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
      SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

      SDL_Surface* hello = NULL;
      SDL_Surface* screen = NULL;

      screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
      hello = Img_Load("img\\hello world.png");

      if(!hello) //check that the load worked
          cout<<"error";

      SDL_BlitSurface(hello, NULL, screen, NULL); //draw image
      SDL_Flip(screen);

      SDL_Delay(2000);

      SDL_FreeSurface(hello); //closing down
      SDL_Quit();

  return 0;
  }
  ```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

'IMG_Load' confirm case in your source file with the library reference when you reach errors like this.

Comment: Img_Load is the correct case according to the documentation. As well, it gives me a different error if I change the case. The scope error implies the function is defined but just not accessible.

Comment: Oh, not sure then. Hate to add more suggestions without effect, but is SDL_image.a being linked?

Comment: As far as I can tell, SDL_image.lib is being linked (it didn't have a .a file, just a .lib). I've added the -lSDL_image flag to the linker settings, the search directories should see it, and Code::Blocks even gives me code completion suggestions for SDL_image functions. Is there some kind of brute force way to bring stuff into scope in C++?